# MS Graph API Search File Name not Content

Tags: api, search, graph, onedrive

I want to return a list of files within a folder on a OneDrive site that match a search pattern using MS Graph API.

The files can be up to a few levels deep in sub folders.

The files are named consistently, for example starting with the letters WKP. My searches always also return files that don't have WKP in the file name. I assume wkp is in the content somewhere for these files.

I can't find anything in the MS Graph docs that tells me how to search only the file names and not the content.

I am using this endpoint /v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{ItemId}/search(q='WKP')

Is there a way to build the query so that it only looks at the file name? I tried q='filename:WKP'

Thanks,